# $\lim_{x\to 0} {\sqrt{1-4x^2}\over x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to solve this? because now I am going to have an exam and I dont know how to solve this

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} {\sqrt{1-4x^2}\over x^2}$$

Comment: Is it undefine?

Comment: Hmm... I guess the question should be $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt{1-4x^2}-1}{x^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your problem? You have
$$\lim_{x\to0} \sqrt{1-4\,x^2} = 1$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to0} x^2 = 0.$$
Now, you should conclude what your limit is.